# Currency symbol Align left and values align right in GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Is it possible to align currency symbol to the left and the value to the right in DevExpress GridView?
[image: Here's an image details link]

Comment: @Dmitry yes,https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_DisplayFormattopic

Comment: if you can ask this question in https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/ 
because it will be helped to you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is beyond the regular text formatting. To accomplish it, you need to manually draw the cell content.

XtraGrid provides the event for this purpose: [CustomDrawCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic). The [event argument object](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseRowCellCustomDrawEventArgstopic) provides a reference to graphics objects, cell boundaries, and other information necessary to draw the cell text manually.

```
private void OnGridViewCustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) {
    switch (e.Column.FieldName) {
        case "Debit":
            DrawDebitCell(e);
            break;  
    }       
}

private void DrawDebitCell(RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) {
    e.Handled = true;
    string text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} {1:n2}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, e.CellValue);
    Size textSize = e.Appearance.CalcTextSizeInt(e.Cache, text, int.MaxValue);
    e.Appearance.DrawBackground(e.Cache, e.Bounds);
    if (Convert.ToInt32(textSize.Width) > e.Bounds.Width)
        e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, text, e.Bounds);
    else {
        StringFormat stringFormat = e.Appearance.GetStringFormat();
        string valueText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:n2}", e.CellValue);
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, e.Bounds, e.Appearance.Font, stringFormat);
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, valueText, e.Bounds, e.Appearance.Font, stringFormat);
    }
}
```

This approach has a few disadvantages:

- The manually drawn cell content is not used by built in [Export and Printing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument115790) system
- It is necessary to calculate the text width to make sure that the value and the currency symbol will not overlap each other. For this purpose, you can use the [CalcTextSizeInt](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressUtilsAppearanceObject_CalcTextSizeInttopic) method of the **AppearanceObject** object available via event arguments. DevExpress uses its own text rendering engine, so the standard [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring(v=vs.110).aspx) method is not useful in this case

Comment: Thanks for your help I just only need it for display purposes.